# Is descructuring or renaming exist for data fields inside angular templates?

Tags: angular

Imagine I have a data with a lot of nested fields like:

```
let item = { a: { b: { c: { title: "object I really need to work with", description: "...", ... } } } }
```

And I need go through an array of such objects:

```
let items: Item[];
```

My template can look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <h1>{{item.a.b.c.title}}</h1>
  <p1>{{item.a.b.c.description}}</p1>
</div>
```

Problem is that I have to use all nested field pointing out every time I need a field of the object I'm really interested in. Is is possible to have some renaming like:

```
<!-- This is not working code -->
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let view = item.a.b.c">
  <h1>{{view.title}}</h1>
  <p1>{{view.description}}</p1>
</div>
```

or desctructuring like:

```
<!-- This is not working code -->
<div *ngFor="let { ... : view } of items">
  <h1>{{view.title}}</h1>
  <p1>{{view.description}}</p1>
</div>
```

?
So I need any possibility of introducing new variable in template which equals internal field of an item.

Comment: Just prepare your list of objects like that in the controller. Why does the template need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need any possibility of introducing new variable in template
>   which equals internal field of an item.

Unfortunately answer is **no**.  In `ngFor` context you can only access to this:

```
export class NgForOfContext<T> {
  constructor(
      public $implicit: T, public ngForOf: NgIterable<T>, public index: number,
      public count: number) {}

  get first(): boolean { return this.index === 0; }

  get last(): boolean { return this.index === this.count - 1; }

  get even(): boolean { return this.index % 2 === 0; }

  get odd(): boolean { return !this.even; }
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5298b2bda34a8766b28c8425e447f94598b23901/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L14)

UPDATE: but you can apply pipe to `ngFor`.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items |propertyAccess: 'a.b.c'; ">
  <h1>{{item |json}}</h1>

</div>
```

Property Access pipe:
@Pipe({ name: 'propertyAccess' })

```
export class PropertyAccessPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(valArr, propPath: string): any {
    let resultArr = [];
    let props = propPath.split('.');
    console.log(valArr, props);
    for (let i = 0; i < valArr.length; i++) {
      let currentObj = valArr[i];
      for (let prop of props) {
        if(currentObj[prop]){
          currentObj = currentObj[prop];
        }
      }

      resultArr.push(currentObj);
    }
    return resultArr;
  }
}
```

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btk5dh)